# Adding webpack to my react app

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to figure out how I can get react, babel (jsx) and bootstrap into a web app.  There doesn't seem to be a single straight forward answer.  I've been down many paths and ended up following the steps on [this guys page](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/setting-up-webpack-for-react-and-hot-module-replacement).  And I'm stuck on his change to the webpack.config.json file.

He states to add the following to webpack.config.json:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ["babel-loader"],
    }
  ],
},
```

So I made my complete change as:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ["babel-loader"],
    }
  ],
},
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/app",
  entry: "./app.js",

  output: {
    filename: "app.js",
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
  },
}
```

That generates errors when I run webpack:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Obviously I do not have the right structure.  But I do not know what that right structure is.   All help is appreciated.

Thank you
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something similar

```
module.exports = {
 entry: './src/app.js',
 output: {
     path: './bin',
     filename: 'app.bundle.js',
 },
 module: {
     loaders: [{
         test: /\.js$/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         loader: 'babel-loader'
     }]
 }}
```

https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage.html